# Incorrect automatic link target in Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app

When I paste a URL containing `%2F` into Mail.app, the automatically generated link target replaces that part with `/`, resulting in a faulty link. Even when manually correcting the link target via `Command-click` → `Hyperlink` → `Edit Link…` the `%2F` part is automatically reverted back to `/` upon clicking `Save`.

Why does this happen and how can I assure a correct link target?

Here is a test URL for you to try: `https://www.figma.com/file/NmeBcl3rhAL5bREti8YGhj/Link-%2F-Paste-Test`

Answer (score 2):

The `%2F` in your URL is an encoded value for a forward slash (`/`), so the output of https://www.figma.com/file/NmeBcl3rhAL5bREti8YGhj/Link-/-Paste-Test is technically correct.

Comment: As it stands, I am unable to mail a working link. Is Figma's link scheme with encoded values instead of slashes the root of the problem, or should Mail.app allow for the encoded value to remain as is?